# Where can I learn more about OpenXML elements specfically for Excel?

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm finding the various elements extremely confusing.  Almost every element seems to have a "Part" associated with it, and I'm not sure how they are all glued together.

Workbook
WorkbookPart
Worksheet
WorkSheetPart

I also have confusion about the DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging vs DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet libraries.

Is there a decent book or guide which can walk me through the basics? I have looked everywhere, but I'm not finding much.

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft's official sites for the SDKs are helpful in case you haven't seen those yet...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Now, if you've looked through the class library reference, you'll see that the documentation provided there isn't very rich.  There aren't examples, just the basics like inheritance hierarchy, namespace, assembly, etc.  For example...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.packaging.workbookpart.aspx

I personally have had the most luck by looking at the actual code, using a tool like JetBrains dotPeek.  And of course the Open XML SDK Productivity Tools are invaluable.  If these didn't exist, any development with Open XML would be even more tedious.  If you're not use the Productivity Tool, it's a must.  The basic exercise is as follows: 1) open Excel or Word, 2) generate the file as you wish to see it, 3) save to disk, 4) open in the Productivity Tool, 5) reflect the code.  It should be noted that the generated code can be very convoluted.  There are usually a lot of non-essentials, and in a few cases the generated code doesn't do exactly what you're expecting (e.g. embedding a spreadsheet in a Word using their code generates a .bin opposed to a .xlsx).  But for the most part, that's the way to go.

Here are a couple other sites I've found helpful as well.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg278316%28v=office.14%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc850837%28v=office.14%29.aspx

http://openxmldeveloper.org/

You might also find Wouter van Vugt's eBook helpful.  It's the closest thing you're going to find to an actual book on the subject.

http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2007/08/13/1970.aspx

And of course the most riveting read may be the actual ECMA specifications:

http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm

There are also a couple open source projects that wrap the Open XML API, in an attempt to simplify things.  For example:

http://closedxml.codeplex.com/

Hope a bit of this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the detailed answer.  Long story short, I found https://epplus.codeplex.com/ which provides a somewhat simple framework for manipulating XLSX files.  It is much easier to use and I strongly recommend it over the native SDK routines.